# Conditionally do INSERT based on SELECT result in postgres sql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-function

How can I do an INSERT to a table based on whether another table has values? Here's an example

```
create table mygroup (
  group_id integer primary key,
  other_id integer not null references othertable(other_id)
);

create table myitem (
  group_id integer not null references mygroup(group_id),
  item_id integer not null
);

create function add_to_group (group_arg integer, item_arg integer, other_arg integer) language sql as $$
  select * from mygroup where group_id = group_arg and other_id = other_arg;
  -- Do the next statement only if the previous one had a result
  insert into myitem (group_id, item_id) values (group_arg, item_arg);
$$;
```

If I were using a plpgsql function it would be possible to do it with `if (found)`. But how can I do it using plain sql function? Is there a way to combine both statements into one, such as doing an INSERT with a JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `exists`:

```
insert into myitem (group_id, item_id) 
    select v.group_id, v.item_id
    from (values (group_arg, item_arg)) v(group_id, item_id)
    where exists (select 1
                  from mygroup g
                  where g.group_id = v.group_id and v.other_id = other_arg
                 );
```

Or, you can use a `select` if only one row in the `mygroup` table should match:

```
insert into myitem (group_id, item_id) 
    select group_arg, item_arg
    from mygroup g
    where g.group_id = group_arg and v.other_id = other_arg;
```

If duplicates are possible, you could tweak this to:

```
insert into myitem (group_id, item_id) 
    select distinct group_arg, item_arg
    from mygroup g
    where g.group_id = group_arg and g.other_id = other_arg;
```

Comment: Btw where does the `v` in the last query come from?

Comment: @user779159 . . . It was a typo.

Comment: Is there any difference between the first and last query or are they the same when duplicates are possible?

Comment: @user779159 . . . The first query only inserts one row at a time.  The last query would allow multiple rows to be inserted, if there were multiple matches in the table.

Comment: What does the `v()` syntax in the first query mean on the 3rd line?

Comment: @user779159 . . . It assigns a table alias and column aliases to the values in the `values()` clause:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html.